# SolrIndexerJob: runtime error

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch, solr, nutch

I'm trying to build a web crawler using Nutch 2.3 + Mongodb+ elasticsearch 1.7. I've configured mongodb store in nutch and it works perfectly. However when I run

```
./bin/nutch index -all
```

I get

```
 IndexingJob: starting
 SolrIndexerJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=apache-nutch-2.3.1.jar, jobid=job_local2085212843_0001
at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:119)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:154)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:176)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:202)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:211)
```

But I'm  not even using Solr. My nutch-site.xml is configured for elastic search. 
nutch-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
    <name>http.agent.name</name> 
    <value>Nofrets Cwawler</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>plugin.includes</name>
    <value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-       (basic|anchor)|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|scoring-opic|indexer-elastic</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>storage.data.store.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoStore</value>
</property>

<!--elastic search properties -->
<property>
<name>elastic.host</name>
<value>localhost</value>
<description>The hostname to send documents to using TransportClient.
Either host and port must be defined or cluster.
</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>elastic.port</name>
<value>9200</value>
<description>
The port to connect to using TransportClient.
</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>elastic.cluster</name>
<value>elasticsearch</value>
<description>The cluster name to discover. Either host and potr must
 be defined or cluster.
</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>elastic.index</name>
<value>nutch</value>
<description>
The name of the elasticsearch index. Will normally be autocreated if it
doesn't exist.
</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>elastic.max.bulk.docs</name>
<value>10</value>
<description>
  The number of docs in the batch that will trigger a flush to
  elasticsearch.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
<name>elastic.max.bulk.size</name>
<value>2500</value>
<description>
The total length of all indexed text in a batch that will trigger a
flush to elasticsearch, by checking after every document for excess 
of this amount.
</description>
</property>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try this:
`bin/nutch index nutch -all`

Comment: Why we have to provide different parameter and why this answer is not accepted ?